# Are questions about diagram drawing on-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I have a finite set of formulas (some of which are pairwise equal) and some binary relations between these formulas.

I want to draw a diagram expressing these relations, to represent visually several theorems.

I have some questions about how the diagram should look.

Are such questions on-topic at math.SE?

Comment: Is there some sort of established way to diagram these relations, and you want to check how a particular relation would be drawn? That would be on topic. If you're inventing your own method and want suggestions, that probably wouldn't be.