# Is how to draw a math-related picture on topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Is a question on how to draw a math-related picture (to be better understood) and what are generally accepted meanings of certain math pictures on topic?

Comment: Similar Questions have been asked here on Meta, including [this one by you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13366/are-questions-about-diagram-drawing-on-topic).  Are you asking whether it would be on-topic for Main Math.SE or on-topic here (on Meta)?

Comment: @hardmath on Math.SE