# Are questions about how to make mathematical plots in Desmos on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

While there is a similar [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13366/are-questions-about-diagram-drawing-on-topic) about drawing diagrams, it was not clear to me from that post whether the software aspect of 'how to draw' something is considering being on topic.

While I *can* plot a lot of things comfortably using the [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), sometimes I find that [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is faster and easier. More relevant to when I would want ask a question on MSE is when I have a feeling that something *should* be easy and doable in Desmos, but a search engine or documentation don't give a direct or clear enough answer.

Is it appropriate to ask such questions as "How do I plot `<thing>` in Desmos such that `<conditions>`?"?

Comment: Questions about math are on topic.  But it sounds like your question is not.

Comment: I had occasion to contact Demos's developers by email.  The response was receptive but suggested a fairly limited resource set and "road map" for new features.  Math.SE will hardly be able to better support their users than they can.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no, it's not on topic.

Longer answer: still no :)  Desmos is a tool that helps you with mathematics, but it's not a mathematical concept or object in its own right.  Questions regarding it should go to either a dedicated Desmos forum (if there are such), or perhaps you might get a useful answer on stackexchange.com itself.

Should mathematics tools be on topic is another question that could arise from this, but I think it's fairly clear that they shouldn't be.  The two major tools for doing mathematics are your brain, and pen-and-paper.  While I do think people would happily ask questions like "what pen is best for solving ODEs?" and "what non-prescription drugs would make it easier to understand motivic cohomology?" I think very few people would think they were on-topic here.  Questions about Desmos, sadly, fall into this category.